# How can I prove that the following function is less than one:

Tags: calculus

Consider the following function:

$\Gamma(Z) = 1 - Z + \frac{\int_{0}^{Z}w(i)di}{w(Z)}$, $~~~$with $i,Z \in[0,1]$

where $w'(i)>0$, i.e., $w$ is increasing in $i$, and also $w>0$.

How can I prove that: $\Gamma <1$

My reasoning was to consider $Z$ large, i.e., $Z$ close to $1$:

a) $1-Z <1$, because $Z>0$, and so this difference gives me a little number, close to zero.

b) if $Z$ is close to $1$, then the ratio $\frac{\int_{0}^{Z}w(i)di}{w(Z)}$ is close to $1$ as well.

What does it prevent to get exactly one?

Comment: I think you need some more assumptions on $\omega$. Is it supposed to be a strictly positive function? Else the definition of $\Gamma$ runs into trouble if $\omega(Z)=0$ for some $Z$.

Comment: $w$ is a strictly positive function. Maybe, I can solve this issue by assuming $w(0)>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$w$ is increasing, so $w(i)/w(Z)\lt1$ for all $0\le i\lt Z$. It follows that: $$\Gamma(Z)=1-Z+\int_0^Z\frac{w(i)}{w(Z)}\,\mathrm{d}i<1-Z+\int_0^Z(1)\,\mathrm{d}i=1$$

You might worry: “but $w(Z)/w(Z)=1$, and $Z$ is in the domain of integration”. This can be resolved with the following observation: changing a function at a single point does not affect the value of the integral. You might as well consider it an integral on $[0,Z)$ rather than $[0,Z]$, there is no difference.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could be a solution to assume that $w(0)>0$?

Comment: @JohnM. As long as $w$ is never zero, that is, as long as $\Gamma$ is defined, there are no issues